# Editor cursor positioning bug

Tags: bug, status-norepro, editor, internet-explorer

I've noticed a recent change (I think) in the way the editor behaves, for me at least.

There seems to be some delay after I hit the enter key before I can move the cursor back to the end of the previous line with the mouse.  It's not always consistent, but typically if I hit the enter key, I must click several times at the end of the previous line before my cursor will move there.  Alternatively, I can click at the beginning of the following line and use the arrow key to move back.  This always seems to work.

To reproduce type a line in the editor.  Hit the enter key and try to use the mouse to move the cursor back to the end of the line you just entered.

Using IE8/WinXP.

**Update**: I don't see this in MacOSX/Safari.   Looks like some recent patch to IE may be the culprit.

Comment: Why on earth are you using the mouse to go back in this scenario? You can't be a programmer! Oh, and get a browser, works with FireFox.

Comment: I described it the easiest way to reproduce, but I think you can't go back to the end of any line.  I find it most annoying when trying to edit code samples.  FWIW, my choice of browser represents the majority of my users not my personal preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have made zero changes to anything editor related in the last month.

If this is a bug, it's either been there for more than a month, or it's not our bug.

Comment: It's a semi-managed system so patches are applied regularly.  Perhaps some IE8 patch is interacting with WMD strangely.  It's more of an annoyance than a real problem.

Answer (score 4):

I can (sort of) replicate this on IE8/Win7, but not really. What I observed wasn't that I needed to click any particular number of times to use the mouse to get to the previous line, but rather that I had to click in *just the right spot.* IE8 was treating any click outside one character size past the line as "take me to the next line," not "take me to the end of this one."

Additionally, because I'm cool like that, I tested this in a non-SO site, and was unable to replicate the same behavior there. The site I tested on (ticket entry in the support desk software I wrote for my company) uses a plain-jane HTML `<textarea>`, with no fancy javascript goodness of any sort attached to it. Not an apples-to-apples comparison by any means.

So yep, there is some form of funky mouse behavior going on with IE8, but what can you do? take Smithers' advice. :)

Comment: I use both FF and IE at work, but I keep IE as my primary browser so that I'm seeing my applications the way the majority of my users do.

Comment: @Cigars and Absinthe are Great: I can replicate on IE8/WinXP on a Plain-Jane `<textarea>` with no fancy javascript goodness.

Comment: @Kip: Hrm. The one I was unable to replicate on was CSS styled (font, border, etc.), but otherwise plain jane. Wonder what was up with *that,* because I had no issues at all. Additionally, testing with John Smithers's page also does not replicate the behavior I'm getting on SO/MSO.

Answer (score 3):

I like Cigar's [textarea approach](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30807/editor-cursor-positioning-bug/30809#30809), so I wrote a quick and dirty test page:

```
<html>
<body>
<textarea rows="10" cols="100">
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

This textarea behaves exactly the same as the MSO one (tested with IE 8).

Comment: WEIRD -- I'm not getting the SO/MSO behavior in IE8/Win7 with this exact code.